# SSL with TCP connection on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, go, ssl, kubernetes

I'm running a TCP server (Docker instance / Go) on Kubernetes.. It's working and clients can connect and do intended stuff. I would like to make the TCP connection secure with an SSL certificate. I already got SSL working with a HTTP Rest API service running on the same Kubernetes cluster by using ingress controllers, but I'm not sure how to set it up with a regular TCP connection. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: you can use `acme/autocert` to setup renewing TLS certificates by simply adding a bit of logic to an existing server. Here is a decent explanation: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Jl3G/https-for-free-in-go-with-little-help-of-lets-encrypt.html I'm not familiar with kubernetes, but using docker volumes you can share the certificate between other docker services easily

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress):

> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing
>   services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a
>   service of type [Service.Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or [Service.Type=LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

Depending on the platform you are using you have different kind of `LoadBalancers` available which you can use to terminate your SSL traffic. If you have **on-premise cluster** you can set up additional **nginx** or **haproxy** server before your Kubernetes cluster which will handle SSL traffic.